# 'Your Teams are moving' dialog box ji-ji-ji-jitters when I scroll

Tags: bug, design, stack-overflow-for-teams, notifications

> [image]

Firefox 106.0.1

Chrome 106.0.5249.119

Comment: For me it seems it occurs randomly, not according to anything